# Get latest table entry by a unique ID with multiple time stamps

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in an Oracle database with machine transactions, and I need to find the time of the last action done to a product.

The products are tracked by a unique id and the machine actions are all time-stamped. The product will not always hit every machine, or else I could just statically call the time stamp from the last machine. I am looking to get data from only a certain process, and after 1/1/2016, the logic of which already works in other queries.

[image]

My query attempt thus far is below, this returns all entries, so I need something to cut down to just the last action:

```
select UniqueID, TimeStamp, MachineName 
from TransactionTable 
where ActionPerformed like 'action' 
and TimeStamp > '1/1/2016' 
group by UniqueID, TimeStamp 
order by UniqueId, TimeStamp desc
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Oracle Database. I was not able to format the table such that it appeared in block form, so I figured the picture was better than nothing. My line returns kept getting lost or double spaced. Thanks for the editing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a sequence for each UniqueID ordered by the date desc:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM    
      (SELECT UniqueID, TimeStamp, MachineName, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)
      AS SEQ
      FROM TransactionTable
      WHERE ActionPerformed LIKE 'action' 
      AND TimeStamp > '1/1/2016' 
  )PR
  WHERE SEQ = 1
```

Comment: `'1/1/2016'` is not a `TIMESTAMP` it is a string literal - Oracle will try to implicitly cast it to a matching data type using `TO_TIMESTAMP` with the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model. If this does not match or, worse, is changed at a later date then the query will fail. It is better to use a timestamp literal `TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 00:00:00'` or perform an explicit call to `TO_TIMESTAMP` specifying the format model.