# How to return the newest record for each sale with certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 4 tables (Sale, User, StatusSale and SaleHistory)

SaleHistory has foreign keys from Sale, User and StatusSale

My table SALEHISTORY

[image]

I want to select the Ids from all last records for each Sale but **ONLY** if the status_sale_id are one of these: [1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]

I'm using this to get the last records by sale:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(sale_id) *
FROM sales_status_histories
ORDER BY sale_id, created_at DESC
```

But with that condition i don't know what i should to do.

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: You can follow the example given here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654857/get-latest-table-entry-by-a-unique-id-with-multiple-time-stamps/44655191#44655191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `WHERE` clause for status_sale_id. 
For example:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
SELECT 
*
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn
FROM sales_status_histories

)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn=1
AND status_sale_id IN (1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work, this query returns only the sales that in any time had this ids and not only in the last record

Comment: Eduardorph Ah yes I missed, above I've edited my earlier post so it now makes a Common Table Expression (CTE) of the filtered data with a row number for the last record by sale_id, then outside the (CTE) I select all the data where row number = 1 i.e. what the last record was by sale_id

Comment: Thank you again, but the query returns almost the same result. The sale_id 1 has the status_sale_id 4 as last, but your query return status_sale_id 11, and 11 was the third record =(

Comment: Hi Eduardorph I think I've got now, this mean the WHERE clause on status_sale_id should be applied outside the CTE, I'll amend the above.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH. It's exacly what i want. You made a amazing job.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Eduardorph, happy to have helped!